# Can select the 1st element but not the entire node list in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am trying to console.log every inner text of elements matching a certain class on a page. Using Nightmare.js/Electron, the working code to select the first element only is:

```
.evaluate(function() {
  console.log(document.querySelector('.result__url__domain').innerText)
}) // returns the first matching element's inner text
```

Although this works, trying to grab them all does not:

```
.evaluate(function() {
  console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.result__url__domain').innerText)
}) // this returns undefined
```

Is this the wrong approach to targeting all of the relevant elements?

Here is the full script code for clarity:

```
var Nightmare_module = require('nightmare')
var nightmare_instance = Nightmare_module({
  show: true // SHOWS the browser
})

var search_term = 'plumber las vegas'

// do a search for the target term

nightmare_instance
  .viewport(1200, 900)
  .goto('https://duckduckgo.com')
  .type('#search_form_input_homepage', search_term)
  .click('#search_button_homepage')
  .wait('.result__a')


  // print domain names to the console

  .evaluate(function() {
    console.log(document.querySelectorAll('.result__url__domain').innerText)
  })

  .then(function (resultObject) {
    console.log(resultObject)
  })
  // .catch(function(errorObject) {
  //   console.error('Search failed. Reason: ', errorObject)
  // })
```

Comment: *querySelectorAll* returns a NodeList that doesn't have an *innerText* (or *textContent*) property. You need to loop over the nodes to get their text content. Or maybe `[].map.call(NodeList, node=>node.textContent).join('');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) returns an array of dom elements, so you have to iterate over each of them to get innerTEXT.

```
.evaluate(function () {
    document.querySelectorAll('.result__url__domain').forEach(function(singleElement){
        console.log(singleElement.innerText);
    });
})
```